# How to display a pictureBox if a certain value is displayed in a label

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am currently writing a Blackjack game for a school project. (below is my code)

```
Public Class frmBlackJack
Public Counter As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnDrawCard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDrawCard.Click
    Randomize()
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Dim Card1 As Integer
    Dim Card2 As Integer
    Dim Card3 As Integer
    Dim Card4 As Integer
    Dim Card5 As Integer

    If Counter >= 1 Then
        btnCheckScore.Enabled = True
    End If
    If Counter = 1 Then
        Card1 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
        lblCard1.Text = Card1
        lblCard1.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter = 2 Then
        Card2 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
        lblCard2.Text = Card2
        lblCard2.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter = 3 Then
        Card3 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
        lblCard3.Text = Card3
        lblCard3.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter = 4 Then
        Card4 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
        lblCard4.Text = Card4
        lblCard4.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter = 5 Then
        Card5 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
        lblCard5.Text = Card5
        lblCard5.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter > 5 Then
        MsgBox("You can't draw anymore cards!")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmBlackJack_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ComputerCard1 As Integer
    Dim ComputerCard2 As Integer
    Dim ComputerCard3 As Integer

    ComputerCard1 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
    ComputerCard2 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
    ComputerCard3 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)

    lblComputerCard1.Text = ComputerCard1
    lblComputerCard2.Text = ComputerCard2
    lblComputerCard3.Text = ComputerCard3

    lblComputerScore.Visible = False
    lblYourScore.Visible = False

    btnCheckScore.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub btnCheckScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckScore.Click
    Dim PlayerSum As Integer
    Dim ComputerSum As Integer

    Dim youWonTitle As String = "You Won!"
    Dim youWonMsg As String = "Great work! Play again?"
    Dim youLostTitle As String = "You Lost!"
    Dim youLostMsg As String = "Better luck next time! Play again?"
    Dim youDrewTitle As String = "You Drew"
    Dim youDrewMsg As String = "That was close! Play again?"

    Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo

    lblComputerCard1.Visible = True
    lblComputerCard2.Visible = True
    lblComputerCard3.Visible = True

    btnDrawCard.Enabled = False

    If Counter < 1 Then
        PlayerSum = Val(lblCard1.Text)
        lblPLayerScore.Text = PlayerSum
        lblPLayerScore.Visible = True
        lblYourScore.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter > 1 Then
        PlayerSum = Val(lblCard1.Text) + Val(lblCard2.Text)
        lblPLayerScore.Text = PlayerSum
        lblPLayerScore.Visible = True
        lblYourScore.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter > 2 Then
        PlayerSum = Val(lblCard1.Text) + Val(lblCard2.Text) + Val(lblCard3.Text)
        lblPLayerScore.Text = PlayerSum
        lblPLayerScore.Visible = True
        lblYourScore.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter > 3 Then
        PlayerSum = Val(lblCard1.Text) + Val(lblCard2.Text) + Val(lblCard3.Text) + Val(lblCard4.Text)
        lblPLayerScore.Text = PlayerSum
        lblPLayerScore.Visible = True
        lblYourScore.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter > 4 Then
        PlayerSum = Val(lblCard1.Text) + Val(lblCard2.Text) + Val(lblCard3.Text) + Val(lblCard4.Text) + Val(lblCard5.Text)
        lblPLayerScore.Text = PlayerSum
        lblPLayerScore.Visible = True
        lblYourScore.Visible = True
    End If

    ComputerSum = Val(lblComputerCard1.Text) + Val(lblComputerCard2.Text) + Val(lblComputerCard3.Text)
    lblComputerTotal.Text = ComputerSum
    lblComputerScore.Visible = True
    lblComputerTotal.Visible = True

    If lblCard1.Text = 1 Then

    End If

    If PlayerSum < 21 And PlayerSum > ComputerSum Then
        Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum > 21 And PlayerSum < 21 Then
        Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum > 21 And ComputerSum < 21 Then
        Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum = 21 And ComputerSum > 21 Then
        Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum = 21 And ComputerSum < 21 Then
        Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum < 21 And ComputerSum > PlayerSum Then
        Dim responseYouLost = MsgBox(youLostMsg, style, youLostTitle)
        If responseYouLost = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum > 21 And ComputerSum < 21 Then
        Dim responseYouLost = MsgBox(youLostMsg, style, youLostTitle)
        If responseYouLost = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum = 21 And PlayerSum <> 21 Then
        Dim responseYouLost = MsgBox(youLostMsg, style, youLostTitle)
        If responseYouLost = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum = PlayerSum Then
        Dim responseYouDrew = MsgBox(youDrewMsg, style, youDrewTitle)
        If responseYouDrew = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum > 21 And ComputerSum > 21 Then
        Dim responseYouDrew = MsgBox(youDrewMsg, style, youDrewTitle)
        If responseYouDrew = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnPlayAgain_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlayAgain.Click
    lblComputerCard1.Visible = False
    lblComputerCard2.Visible = False
    lblComputerCard3.Visible = False
    lblComputerCard1.Text = ""
    lblComputerCard2.Text = ""
    lblComputerCard3.Text = ""

    lblCard1.Visible = False
    lblCard2.Visible = False
    lblCard3.Visible = False
    lblCard4.Visible = False
    lblCard5.Visible = False
    lblCard1.Text = ""
    lblCard2.Text = ""
    lblCard3.Text = ""
    lblCard4.Text = ""
    lblCard5.Text = ""
    Counter = 0

    Dim ComputerCard1 As Integer
    Dim ComputerCard2 As Integer
    Dim ComputerCard3 As Integer

    ComputerCard1 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
    ComputerCard2 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
    ComputerCard3 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
    lblComputerCard1.Text = ComputerCard1
    lblComputerCard2.Text = ComputerCard2
    lblComputerCard3.Text = ComputerCard3

    btnDrawCard.Enabled = True
    btnCheckScore.Enabled = True

    lblComputerTotal.Text = ""
    lblPLayerScore.Text = ""
    lblComputerTotal.Visible = False
    lblPLayerScore.Visible = False
    lblComputerScore.Visible = False
    lblYourScore.Visible = False


End Sub

Private Sub btnQuit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub StartGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartGameToolStripMenuItem.Click
    btnDrawCard.PerformClick()

End Sub

Private Sub QuitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles QuitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

What I want to happen, is for a card (picture) to be displayed, if a certain number is also displayed in a label. For example if the value 1 is displayed in lblCard1 then picture of an ace pops up on the form.

(Disclaimer) Not sure if this is actually possible. I have been searching around on the internet for a solution however I couldn't find anything. If you know how to do this please respond.

Thanks

Comment: Your deal-a-card method is very flawed.  You cannot just pick a random number to emulate a deck of cards.  There is nothing in your code to prevent more 4 of any value from being picked.  Also those `Card#` variables arent being used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'd strongly recommend coding with an "Option Strict On" declaration at the very top of your form's code module rather than relying on implicit type casting.

Secondly, I'd recommend using a "Select Case" statement rather than a long series of If statements.

There are numerous ways of achieving your desired outcome. It depends on whether you want the picture box to be hidden or to be visible but displaying no image when the key number is not displayed.

Using the example of an ace being shown when lblCard1.Text = "1" and "picAce" is a picture box on your form, one approach would be:

To hide the ace:

```
picAce.Visible = (lblCard1.Text = "1")
```

To show the picture box and load it from a file located in the path "C:\pics\ace.jpg" if "1" is displayed in lblCard1 or empty the picture box if another number is displayed:

```
picAce.Image = If(lblCard1.Text = "1", Image.FromFile("C:\pics\ace.jpg"), Nothing)
```

You could also add the ace image to your project's or form's resources and load it from one of those repositories if you did not want to rely on sourcing the image from the file system.

EDIT:

The structure of a Select Case clause would look like this:

```
Select Case Counter

    Case 1

    Case 2

    Case 3

    Case 4

    Case 5

    Case Else

End Select
```

Comment: Thankyou, can you please show an example on how to use a select case statement @Guru Josh